# Local to linux copy

Tags: linux

I am trying to copy few files from local desktop to linux server through winscp. But the permission of the same file is different while copying from different users. How can i set a default permission of 755 while copying from local to linux server irrespective of the user or user permissions used to login to linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first of all, the file permissions are the same no matter who the user is. Every Unix file has a set of permissions and that's it. As I get it, some of the users that want to copy / manipulate the file do not have permission to do it. What I would do, is add all these users (I assume you know beforehand what users need to have permission to these files) to a group (say winscp group or whatever name you want) and change the group of ownership of that file to that group.

To sum up:

1. Create a new group (`groupadd <groupname>`)
2. Add all your users that want to manipulate these files to that group (`useradd -G {group-name} username`)
3. Change the group ownership of that file to the group you created ( `chgrp <groupname> <filename>`  OR   `chgrp <groupname> <directoryname>`)

Answer (score 0):

Default permission in Linux are controlled by the umask value. In order to create files with default permissions of 755 you have to issue the following command:

```
umask 022
```

The resulting permissions are calculated with the following formula:

```
777 - umask
```

Comment: hi redobot, thanks for your response. Do we need to set umask for all the users separately or is there any option we can set it for all the users at server level? Also does value of umask gets picked up while logging on linux server through winscp?

Comment: You can both set it for user-level or all the users. In order to change the umask for all the users you have to modify the /etc/profile file. In order to set the umask for your user only you have to modify the value in your .bashrc. I'm not sure but I think this should work for files uploaded by winscp also.